# ¿Cómo extraigo fechas con Grep?

Tags: grep

Estoy tratando de sacar fechas especificas de un texto y pasarlas a otro texto pero no se porque no funciona mi comando, alguien me puede ayudar porfavor.

`egrep "185.-10-"|"186.-10-"|"187.-10-"|"188.-10-"|"189.-10-"|"190.-10-"|"191.-10-"|"192.-10-"|"193.-10-"|"194.-10-"|1950-10-" TemperaturasMadrid >> Primer_Periodo1850_1950`

Comment: no es lo mismo `grep "bla"|"ble"` que `grep "bla|ble"`. El primero busca "bla" seguido de "ble", mientras que el segundo busca "bla" o "ble". Creo que buscas lo segundo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta sintaxis mejor:

```
egrep -E "185.-10-|186.-10-|187.-10-|188.-10-|189.-10-|190.-10-|191.-10-|192.-10-|193.-10-|194.-10-|1950-10-" TemperaturasMadrid >> Primer_Periodo1850_1950
```

Piensa que el simbolo `>>` hará un *append*, es decir, agregará el resultado al final del contenido existente en el archivo `Primer_Periodo1850_1950`.

Si lo que quieres es reescribirlo de nuevo usa solo un `>`.

El parametro `-E` que les pasamos al egrep, segun `man egrep`, quiere decir lo siguiente:

> Pattern Syntax
> -E, --extended-regexp
> Interpret PATTERNS as extended regular expressions (EREs, see below).

Es decir, que interpreta lo que venga a continuación como una [*expresión regular*](https://juncotic.com/grep-y-las-expresiones-regulares-basicas-y-extendidas/), la cual, en tu caso, esta llena de `|`, que vendrian a ser el equivalente al operador **OR**.

No debes entrecomillar las cadenas de texto entre los `|`, tal como ves en mi solución planteada, porque el comando no lo acepta de ese modo. Usa solo las comillas dobles para encerrar la expresión regular completa.